# How can you extract string patterns from a column in a data frame and create a new data frame column containing the extracted strings?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a search key column for my data frame. I would like to extract certain string patterns from my data frames column to be used for creating a new search key column along the length of my data frame. For example:

```
x <- c(1:4)
y <- c("BLUE,BALL","BALL,RED","BIG,GREEN,BALL","BALL")
dat <- data.frame(x,y)
```

which gives,

```
>dat

x        y
1        BLUE,BALL
2        BALL,RED
3        BIG,GREEN,BALL
4        BALL
```

Now I would like to make a new search key column in the data frame based off of the occurrences of color patterns in dat$y. I would like to use :

```
    pattern="RED|GREEN|BLUE"
```

For any instances of 'pat' not being recognized in dat$y, I would like to leave empty or 'NA' in the elements place. I would like my results to look something like below:

```
>new.dat

x        y                search.color
1        BLUE,BALL        BLUE
2        BALL,RED         RED
3        BIG,GREEN,BALL   GREEN
4        BALL             NA
```

I have used

```
dat$first <-do.call(rbind,lapply(strsplit(dat[,2],split=" "), function(x) head(x,1)))
```

for creating a first word search key filter along my data frame but now I am searching for methods that allow more control for selecting search keys using grepl or other means. Any help or resources are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stringr::str_extract` should do what you want easily.

```
pat <- "(RED|GREEN|BLUE)"
dat <- transform(dat,search.color=stringr::str_extract(y,pat))
## dat
##   x              y search.color
## 1 1      BLUE,BALL         BLUE
## 2 2       BALL,RED          RED
## 3 3 BIG,GREEN,BALL        GREEN
## 4 4           BALL         <NA>
```

I'm sure there's a base-R `gsub()` solution as well, but it's not as obvious to me ...

Comment: Thank you. That is a very nice solution. Is it possible to use your above solution for creating search key column for classifications. For example, instead of returning extracted pattern, return "color" for any strings in dat$y that contain pat<-"(RED|GREEN|BLUE)"?

Comment: something like `ifelse(grepl("(RED|GREEN|BLUE)",y),"color","no_color")` (or `NA`, or whatever you want, for the alternative value)

Comment: Instead of the user defining the colors in a pattern is it possible to use [colors()] function in R for extracting color from the column?

Comment: you should ask new questions rather than continuing to ask new questions in the comments ...

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same thing. Sorry about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We could also use `gregexpr/regmatches` from `base R`

```
dat$search.color <- sapply(regmatches(dat$y,gregexpr(pat, dat$y)),`[`,1)
dat$search.color
#[1] "BLUE"  "RED"   "GREEN" NA
```

#### data

```
pat <- "(RED|GREEN|BLUE)"
```

Comment: Thanks. I will ask the same question as I did for the other solution above. Is it possible to use your above solution for creating search key column for classifications. For example, instead of returning extracted pattern, return "color" for any strings in dat$y that contain pat<-"(RED|GREEN|BLUE)"? I believe I have seen this done with gsub() before. Thank you again.

Comment: @ryry  Looks like it is answered by BenBolker in the comments.